# Share VPN to Xbox One

Tags: networking, router, windows-8.1, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a PPTP VPN (which is a ping reduction service) on my Xbox One through my PC as a gateway. Here's what I have:

- They gave me a `.pbk` file.
- 2 network adapters. One (Ethernet2) connected to my Xbox and the other (Ethernet) to the
  modem router
- Windows 8.1, Update 1
- Xbox One

When I double-click on the `.pbk` file and select `Properties` and go to `Sharing` tab, I don't have the option to share the connection:

[image: No sharing option]

Then, I tried to create the connection myself. I went to control panel, and selected "Set up a new ..." and followed. It then gave me the option to share it. I selected the options as follows **Please note the 2 checkboxes are unchecked.**:

[image: Sharing]

On the process to do this, it gave me 2 message boxes. One which said that the user/pass is not shared for all users and the other said this:

[image: Message]

I selected "Yes" and then connected to the VPN. It connected successfully. Now my connections looks like these:

[image: Connections]

After this I went to Xbox One. Selected "Automatic" for both IP and DNS settings but it didn't connect. Then I tried manual settings. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Xbox]

But it didn't work either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

### Update

I tested the CyberGhost's VPN and shared the `TAP-Windows Adapter V9`'s connection and it worked perfectly. Something tells me the problem is with the mentioned VPN. But why doesn't it work?!