# Connect Xbox to VPN through DD-WRT Router

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I'm trying to connect my Xbox One to a ping reduction service which is a PPTP VPN. I can connect to it in Windows 8.1 without any kind of problem. Here are the settings for security tab:

[image: VPN Security Tab]

Now, I bought a TP-Link TL-WR740N router and flashed a [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com) firmware to it so that I can connect my Xbox to this VPN via this router. Here's what I want:

```
               +----------+         +---------+         +-----+
Internet +-->  | Modem    |  +----> |Router   | +-----> |Xbox |
               |          |         |         |         |     |
               +----------+         +---------+         |     |
                                                        +-----+
```

In the above picture, the router is connected to the internet via the Modem. I want to use the firmware on the router to the VPN so basically all the output from the router is connected to that VPN and has a lower ping.

Here are my configurations (click to see images):

- [Modem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAvqt.png)
- [Router - Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAqwG.png)
- [Router - Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah1FZ.png)
- [Router - VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR6sK.png)

After I reboot the router, it connects to the Internet but not the VPN. I can see this in the [status tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVuC.png)

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my approach or the VPN. I tried to find a free VPN for testing purpose but I didn't manage to connect to them in Windows so I don't think they're a good candidate for a test.

Also, there's a possibility that something's different about this particular VPN as [I've previously had a problem sharing it](https://superuser.com/questions/861548/share-vpn-to-xbox-one) but then again, I'm not sure because I haven't been able to test it with another VPN.

Comment: Couple of questions.  Why are you using two routers?  From reading about the WAG120N it does support VPN.  Are there VPN settings in your Linksys WAG120N?  If there are no VPN settings in the first router (Linksys) then the 2nd router (TP-Link/DDWRT) will take it's VPN settings up the pipe to the Linksys and then not know where to go.  Maybe it's setup, but did not see it in your question/pictures.  On you're Windows 8.1 device are you connected to the Linksys or the TP-Link router?

Comment: First, I want to say that I reverted to the stock firmware for my TP-Link router and it connects to the VPN without any issues so the issue was with DDWRT. 1. I want to connect to my VPN through Xbox One which currently doesn't support VPN. 2. It doesn't matter if the Linksys doesn't support it, why should it? 3. On my Windows machine I'm connected to Linksys modem/router.